# Adding a theme to MVC page, can't find css file

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Its been a little while by now, that I have been trying to understand MVC. I do understand the basics now and I also noticed, themes or css files can be added to a MVC site. When I try to do this, it seems my CSS file is not being found. This is the head of my _Layout.cshtml code:

```
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Bierownie</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Earthlingtwo/style.css")"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

I am not really sure what I should put at the link tag. I noticed that in the other (standard auto-generated(Razor)) _Layout.cshtml file, something like this was being used:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

But it seemed that the code wouldn't understand if I put that same bit of code in the Layout's head, from which I want to use. I also tried to search on the web and I think it had something to do with the config file, although I'm not sure. A red curve would appear beneath Styles and Scripts.

If anyone could tell me how I simply could link a css file in a newly created layout file, I would be able to go further with my MVC site.

I am also not so sure if this question has already been asked and/or solved, so please let me know, as I couldn't find any answers.

---

As you can see in this picture:
[image]

There's a config file which will break the theme. Someone else noticed it and it did cause a problem.

Comment: are sure files exists on this path and Content folder is in root directory of project

Comment: http://oi60.tinypic.com/wgrugy.jpg

Comment: if Layout file is also in that folder then why not simple only give file name style.css

Comment: Ofcourse I already tried that...

Comment: I agree with Ehsan that the file probably isn't there. You can use Fiddler (or a similar tool) to check the actual file request. The Styles/Scripts renders are using bundling to combine and minify multiple files. A normal <link> in the <head> it what it sounds like you are after.

Comment: press Ctrl+F5 in your browser to load page without caching

Comment: Look at the link with the image I pasted in the above comment. The file is definitely there ain't it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response etc! Unfortunately none of those things work. :S

Comment: What is rendered in the link href tag when using your code? Is it just empty?

Comment: Nevermind, it seemed like a config file was placed in wrong folder, causing the code not to retreive the css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can just Drag&Drop css file from solution explorer to your layout page.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle uses better. Try this:

[ASP.NET - Using Bundle and Minification in ASP.NET MVC 4 and ASP.NET Web Forms 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn168847.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In your question, the path to style is noted as Content/Earthlingtwo/style.css, where in your graphic it's Content/Earthlingtwo/images/style.css. In the Earthlingtwo folder, is a site.css file Content/Earthlingtwo/Site.css

You need to correct your href to the correct path

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Earthlingtwo/images/style.css")"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Earthlingtwo/Site.css")"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

depending on which is the correct file.

[image]